# CI return all request to 404 page in host

Tags: codeigniter

IN xampp CI work fine . but in host all request redirect to 404 page . i checked all config file and no problem . i cant find problem . sorry . i am new on CI and sorry for my poor english .[online test](http://www.irangreenschools.com/)

htacces file content :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Have you followed the ucfirst that codeigniter says to for filenames and classes example here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: thanks i think error because upercase .